How do I convert a WAV file to an MP3 file without adding a split second of silence?
I am currently making a mixtape where every song transitions perfectly into the next one.
I made sure to check the zero crossing so that there is no clicks (or silence) at the end of the tracks, and when I rendered the project into WAV files it indeed transitioned perfectly from song to song.
When I then rendered the project in MP3 (the same way I rendered it in WAV), it added short moments of silence at the beginning of every track which ruined the transitions. I tested on both the Windows media player and Spotify local files.
I also attempted to convert the WAV files into MP3 using an online converter but I got the same results. I searched online about this topic and I did find people asking the same question but the only answer they got is that MP3 just works like that. But if it really does work like that, how come other albums and mixtapes I downloaded in MP3 from the internet to listen to on Spotify (with local files of course) do transition perfectly?

After you create the MP3 file, have you considered to edit it in Audacity to identify and remove the silence?

@fred_dot_u editing a compressed format to save it and having it recompressed again is not a good idea and will cause for degredation.

Use ffmpeg for encoding.
ffmpeg -i your_file.wav -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k your_file.mp3

If the silence is still there, it's in the .wav file.

To process every .wav file in the folder, use:
Linux
for file in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k "${file[@]/%wav/mp3}"; done

Windows
# Get all .wav files in folder
$wavFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.wav

# Iterate over files
foreach ($file in $wavFiles) {
    # Construct the output path, replace .wav with .mp3
    $outputFile = $file.FullName -replace '\.wav$', '.mp3'
    
    # Run FFmpeg
    Start-Process -FilePath "ffmpeg" -ArgumentList @(
        "-i", $file.FullName,
        "-c:a", "libmp3lame",
        "-b:a", "192k",
        $outputFile
    ) -Wait
}

I'm terrible at Powershell, but that has to be close. I can't guarantee it like the shell command.
